Gack Id -1217291834 when installing the package
When I try to install a package, I receive and error UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 85657452-846981 (-1217291834).
Why does it happen and what is the reason of this error?

This is the stack trace message
Couldn't find CDP tenant ID. Please enable CDP first.

The reason for this error is the fact that the target subscriber org doesn't have the Data Cloud enabled while the package contains data cloud features.
